# What does +2 Range mean?

Tags: terraria

the Chain item reads:

> +2 Range
>     can be placed
>  
>     material
>     can be climbed on

what does +2 Range mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It simply means you can place them 2 blocks farther away than you could normal blocks and the rope.

> Chains can be placed and used like Rope and offer the same climbing
>   speed (1,000ft in 14 seconds), **however you can place it at a slightly
>   longer range.**

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chain)